# How to have different calculations in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Users on my platform and each user has a different status attached to them. What I want to achieve is that based on the Users status I want a specific calculation to be done and displayed in the same column. Based on each Users status, the calculation involves 3 dates: Last Review Date, Actual End Date and Today's Date (I will be using the `GETUTCDATE()` function for this but for the purpose of this post I have added a date into this column).

Below we have the 6 different Statuses and the calculations that go with each:

- Draft - If the user is in this status there is no calculation and the value in the column should be NULL
- Active - If the user is in this status the calculation should be: the amount of days it has been from todays date and their Last Review Date.
- Completed - If the user is in this status there is no calculation and the value in the column should be NULL
- Withdrawn - If the user is in this status there is no calculation and the value in the column should be NULL
- Temporarily Withdrawn - If the user is in this status the calculation should be: the amount of days it has been from todays date and their Actual End Date.
- Archived - If the user is in this status there is no calculation and the value in the column should be NULL

See link to image for what the table looks like [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQl2d.png).
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: Please do not add images to your question with sample data, as per question guide put sample data as text, this also applies to expected outcome

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `CASE` on the display part. Something like:

```
SELECT
   (...)
   ,CASE
     WHEN status = 'Active' THEN <calculation for status Active>
     WHEN status = 'Temporarily Withdrawn' THEN <calculation for status Temporarily Withdrawn>
     ELSE NULL
   END AS calculation
   ,(...)
FROM (...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to use a CASE Statement for this calculation but I am getting the following error message: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. I believe this may be to do with the Status not being a unique enough identifier as some users could have the same Status?

Comment: That is  consequence of using an sub query as one of the CASE arguments. Try refactoring that query so that it only returns one single value, if possible Limit or Top operators should help achieve that goal.